# Calculate the area of $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2=1(ac-b^2＞0,c＞0)$

Tags: real-analysis

I can write it as $\frac{ac-b^2}{c}x^2+c(y+\frac{b}{c}x)^2=1$, and I want to let $u=x, v=y+\frac{b}{c}x$.

It is easy to calculate the area after substituting. However, I do not know how to return it back.

How should I do in the next step? Is my method right?

Comment: The area of an ellipse is $\pi\times$ the semi-major axis $\times$ the semi-minor axis. Hope this helps.

Comment: What have you learned about changes of variable in integration? (Think Jacobian.)